# Punctuation use for separating lists between "between" for clarity

Tags: punctuation, commas, semicolons

What is the best way to punctuate the following two sentences so the reader is not confused?

1) For transfers between station A and shelf B AND processing device and automated stocker, use chain Q.

2) For transfers between station A, shelf B, and desk C AND processing device, automated stocker, and shelf Z, use chain Q.

To be clear the transfer occurs between the following parenthesized words (station and shelf B) AND (processing device and automated stocker) in 1) and (station A, shelf B, and desk C) AND (processing device, automated stocker, and shelf Z).

These sentences are part of a long sentence, so I simplified it for this question.  Thank you very much for your help!!

Comment: You need to rephrase if anyone is to make anything of the sentences.

Answer (score 1):

For that precise wording, I would use:

- For transfers between station A and shelf B, and the processing device and automated stocker, use chain Q.

That's as clear as I can make it without rephrasing.

For the second sentence... I think the only way to do it would be:

- Use chain Q for transfers between: station A, shelf B, and desk C, and; processing device, automated stocker, and shelf Z.